# Why all the cards get activated when i click the active button of a specific card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click the active button of a specific card to make it active, all of the cards get activated. Here I used the variable className and I set it manually to the value : "card mb-3 border-3", and I want when clicking the button active, the className should have a border of the value : "border-info", but I still get all the cards activated although I used the parameter id to differentiate between them. Please how to solve this problem?

```
function GridMod({articles, updateArticleList}) {

    const [className, setClassName] = useState("card mb-3 border-3");

    const Status = (id) => {
        let classname = className;
        
        if(articles.filter((article) => article.id === id))
        {
            if(classname == "card mb-3 border-3"){
                setClassName("card mb-3 border-info border-3")
            }
            console.log("activated!")
        }
    };`

    const Remove = async (id) => {
        try {
            await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/articles/${id}`);
            const updatedArticles = articles.filter((article) => article.id !== id);
            updateArticleList(updatedArticles);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
                <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        articles.map((article)=>(    
                        <div className="col-sm" >
                        <div className={className} key={article.id}  style={{width:"18rem"}}>
                            <img className="card-img-top" src={article.image} alt="Card image cap"style={{height:"250px" }} />
                            <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">{article.title}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">{article.description}</p>
                            <Link to={`/blog/edit/${article.id}`} className='btn btn-primary'>
                            <AiFillAlipayCircle/> Edit blog
                            </Link>  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button onClick={() =>Remove(article.id)}>Delete</button>  &nbsp;&nbsp;   
                            <button onClick={()=>Status(article.id)}>Active</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default GridMod;
```

Comment: Well you have only a single state for the classname of *every* card. You'll need a separate state for each card. Use an array or object, or rather store the id of the active card. Or create a new component for cards where each can have its own boolean state.

Comment: I don't get it, can you please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every article being returned from your `.map()` is being provided the same stateful value `className` being used by all other articles.**

*From your snippet:*

```
<div className={className} key={article.id}  style={{width:"18rem"}}>
```

Thus, it doesn't matter which `article.id` you supply to `Status`, as you will always end up updating every single `<div>` you supplied that `className` to when you call `setClassName`.

If you want to use State in order to achieve this result, it's better to store the `id` of the article itself and compare it to the `id` received for each iteration of the `map`. If they equal, you can apply the desired `className` in the `render` using a ternary statement. This way, we can avoid a shared `className` stateful variable from changing all the articles whenever it updates.

```
// sample articles with id for purpose of demonstration
export default function GridMod({ articles = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] }) {
  // will store id of currently active button
  const [active, setActive] = useState();

  const Status = (id) => {
    setActive(id);
  };

  // the rest of your component render can remain the same, but the .map() will have to change
  return articles.map((article) => (
    // removing non-relevant elements for demonstration
    // if article id is equal to active id, we apply the className "active-class"
    <div className={article.id === active ? "active-class" : "inactive-class"} key={article.id}>
      <button onClick={() => Status(article.id)}>Active</button>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

*Output:*

```
<div class="inactive-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
<div class="inactive-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
<div class="inactive-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
```

Clicking any one of the above buttons will change the `className` of that button's div, and only that button's div, to `"active-id"`.

This way, you can even set a default active if you'd like by changing the invocation of `useState()`. Using the example articles defined above:

```
// active id default = 2
const [active, setActive] = useState(2);
```

*Output*

```
<div class="inactive-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
<div class="inactive-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
<div class="active-class" style="">
  <button>Active</button>
</div>
```